# help to analyse a log file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

How does `sed 's/\[//'` work in case of analyzing log files for the time stamp fields? 
I found a solution online and I saw this line `"$(head-1 "$1" | awk '{print $4}'| sed 's/\[//')"`. Can someone please explain the functionalities of each.

sample logs,

```
64.12.96.106 - - [13/Sep/2003:18:02:54 -0600] ... 216.93.167.154 - - [15/Sep/2003:16:30:29 -0600]
```

Comment: You need to give us the input on which you would like to apply this logic. Anyway here sed is deleting [ in the field.

Comment: This is an example 64.12.96.106 - - [13/Sep/2003:18:02:54 -0600] ...
216.93.167.154 - - [15/Sep/2003:16:30:29 -0600] ... And it returns 12/sep/2003:18:02:54

Comment: @user174831 Put the example,formatted, into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not provided any specific logs which you are analyzing it, here is the functionalities of each operation,

- `head -1 "$1"` : Print the first line of FILE, which is passed as an argument `$1`
- `awk '{print $4}'`: Print 4th column from the output of `head -1 "$1"`
- `sed 's/\[//'` : remove `[` from the final output

Example for `sed`,

```
rahul@rahul$ sed 's+\[++' <<< "rah[ul"
rahul@rahul$ rahul

# In your case 

rahul@rahul$ sed 's+\[++' <<< "[13/Sep/2003:18:02:54 -0600]"
rahul@rahul$ 13/Sep/2003:18:02:54 -0600]

# for hello/world

rahul@rahul$ sed 's+\/++' <<< "hello/world"
rahul@rahul$ helloworld
```

Comment: what if i want to remove a particular sub string from a special character, for eg hello/world and i want to remove from /........ How can i do it

Comment: @user174831 see my updated answer